# Wanting to convert CFScript source code into Java source code

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfml

I am in the process of moving some old ColdFusion source code across to Java. Most of it is in CFScript format and this does a good enough job of converting CFML to CFScript: https://cfscript.me/ (Thanks Pete Freitag)

I wonder if there are utilities to convert CFScript source to Java source code. Note: I am NOT talking about decompiling java class bytecode.

The CFScript syntax is pretty close to Java syntax and I am looking for a way to do some of the heavy lifting to reduce the amount of hand-editing.

Any thoughts? If not, I might have a go at writing something.
Thanks,
Murray

**EDIT:** More background:

I want to migrate an application completely from CF to Java. But, it is a big app and my idea is to incrementally create "drop in" java classes to replace existing CFCs and write new code as Java classes in the meantime. I can execute a Java class in CF and use CFCs in Java via createDynamicProxy().

At its most simple form I can then change from

```
someObj = createObject("component","SomeCFC"); 
msg = someObj.getMessage();
```

to

```
someObj = createObject("java","SomeClass"); 
msg = someObj.getMessage();
```

I am not looking to "port" it (as we would say in the old days ;-) ), just to run the CFC through a "parser" that did some of the obvious code changes before I then work through and fix the harder stuff and refactor. That way, at least I have the business logic and same methods and I can run it through the tests.

This might be pie-in-the-sky but I imagine I am not the first person who needed to go down this particular migration path.

Comment: My suggestion regarding changing the programming language of existing applications is to not do so directly.  Determine what the application does first, then use that as a specification.

Comment: Thanks. See Edit abive

Comment: Your two codes examples are identical. Can you please edit and correct your post?

Comment: Your two codes examples are identical. Can you please edit and correct your post?

Comment: No they are no identical. In ColdFusion you can create an instance of a CF Component (CFC) with `createObject("component","SomeCFC")`. You also have the option of creating an instance of a Java class `createObject("java","SomeClass")`. Once instantiated, the method access uses the same syntax: `msg = someObj.getMessage()`

Comment: I would be skeptical using such a conversion tool if it exists. Java being as strict as it is means conversion from CF would require review to ensure correct data types are set and carrying over in a proper (performant) manner. CF shelters us from a lot of the more specific Java APIs for representing data. Any tool out there would be doing guesswork I wouldn't be comfortable relying on. In my opinion, manual conversion is the way to go. If there's a pattern you can automate for your benefit then sure, do it. Your mention of breaking into classes to be consumed by CF sounds like a solid start.

Comment: Thanks @Tony. Yes, indeed, I am not thinking I would rely on it but thinking it could do some of the stuff I will need to do manually in the editor! I can then use the linting etc in vsCode to pick up the stuff I still need to change. Then, of course, run it through my tests.